# Unity - Create terrain in Blender?

Tags: unity, performance

I am going to make a terrain ( not too big ) for my RTS and I was wondering whether to use Unity's terrain tool or create a terrain in Blender and import it to Unity?..I have been told that Unity's terrain is intense work for the mobile GPU..So would it be any good to make the terrain in Blender ( in terms of performance )?

Comment: [See the comments on this previous question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130242/handmade-terrain-vs-terrain-engine-in-unity?rq=1). As it was in that question, your best bet is to make a simple test of each version and try it on your target hardware. That will tell you whether the performance difference is serious enough for your scenario to be worth re-implementing Unity's terrain features for a custom mesh.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about performance but I guess that if you import terrain from blender it'll be just a mesh without terrain's LOD system, you'll need to write it yourself, same thing with grass and detail meshes, you'll need to make your own LOD system for them. It'll require extra work but I'm almost sure that it will be at least a little faster. If you can export terrain with big texture for it, it'll save processing power that is needed for splatmapping in shader.